# Runtime cost of inheritance (without virtuality) in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, inheritance

In C++ compiled with -O3, does inheritance without virtuality have a cost in terms of :

- execution time
- memory

If the answer is yes : why ?

As an example : are MyClass1 and MyClass2 equivalent in terms of performance and memory ?

[image]

Comment: In theory there should be no performance difference.  In practice...well, go measure your particular scenarios and find out (I wouldn't expect any difference at high optimization levels, but perhaps the compiler might fail to inline base class constructor calls, or it might fail to perform EBO, or... all sorts of things _could_ happen, it could even be faster.  The way to find out is to measure).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the cost of inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210412/what-is-the-cost-of-inheritance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> execution time

Of what? Functions are resolved statically, so function calls are the same. `MyClass1`'s constructor will call the constructors of base classes, and its destructor will call destructors of base classes, so for construction & destruction there may be some overhead. *Maybe*. Some compilers might optimize the calls away.

> memory

This will be the same, both only have a member `double`. Theoretically. Depends on the implementation I guess, as it's not mandated by the standard, but most commonly there will be no memory overhead.

**Note** that deleting an object `MyClass1` through a pointer to `Derived` results in undefined behaviour, because there's no `virtual` destructor.

**Note 2** inheritance without polymorphism is a code smell. Not saying it's wrong, but in most cases composition is better.

Comment: And since the constructors and destructors are pretty simple, they should be inline and the compiler will generate the same code for both versions.

Comment: About construction and destruction : will compilers optimize temporary construction/destruction for overloaded operators defined in Base ?

Comment: @Vincent - I don't understand the question. There's no inherent connection between overloaded operators and temporaries.

Comment: @Vincent calls are resolved statically. They will behave the same whether you use inheritance or not.

Answer (score -3):

In terms of memory space, I guess your MyClass1 consumes more because it needs to keep track of all class structure and relations. For performance I don't see any notable difference.

Comment: Seconded. Care to give a citation, or at least reasoning?

Comment: Class structure and relations are handled by the compiler. With no virtuals, there's no runtime space penalty for these.

Comment: I know. I thought it was what he/she asked.